# minimum requirements for a grails web application to be deployed

Tags: grails

I am going deploy grails web application to another computer. That another computer already has an apache tomcat server and a mysql server.

Do I need to install groovy on that machine where I would deploy my grails application? or other libraries? or just java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is java and a webapp container like tomcat.  When you create a war file with `grails war`, the war file will contain all the dependencies of your project, including all of grails and groovy.  This does make the war files quite large, but they are extremely easy to deploy.

Comment: yeah, I tried deploying on my machine and it is really easy with grails. thanks for the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Infact all you need is a webcontainer (some webcontainers have JRE built in them)

The war file that you create by running "grails war" will build a war file with all libraries including inside it.