# Grails 3 WAR Deployment Server Prerequisites

Tags: grails, deployment, war, prerequisites, grails3.2.0

I am new to Grails (v 3.2.3) and I was wondering about what prerequesites a grails 3 WAR will actually typically need to run on a server:

Do I only need a Tomcat and JRE installed or are there other installations like GDK and grails to be made?

I was trying to figure out from the docs
http://docs.grails.org/3.2.3/guide/deployment.html#deploymentContainer

here it says:

> Application servers
>
> Ideally you should be able to simply drop a WAR file created by Grails into any application server and it should work straight away. However, things are rarely ever this simple. [The Grails website](http://grails.org/Deployment) contains a list of application servers that Grails has been tested with, along with any additional steps required to get a Grails WAR file working.

The URL is protected and I cannot access even after setting up an account: https://grails.org/Deployment

I know this might be a duplicate of "[minimum requirements for a grails web application to be deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751664/minimum-requirements-for-a-grails-web-application-to-be-deployed)" but I would prefer to gather some official background on this topic before placing an order at "the wrong" webhoster.

**Update**:

Thank you very much for your replies. By now I also found these, so it became clear that a grails WAR can even be run as a "standalone" java application

http://docs.grails.org/3.2.3/guide/gettingStarted.html#deployingAnApplication

```
grails war
java -Dgrails.env=prod -jar build/libs/mywar-0.1.war
```

http://docs.grails.org/3.2.3/guide/gettingStarted.html#supportedJavaEEContainers

Comment: grails would only be required for development environment, Grails provides you with its cool functionalities. When you have finished developing you generate a war file. Grails runs a magical process which converts all your code into a war file. You then place the war file into a container such as most typically tomcat. Tomcat itself requires you to be running at the very least JRE. It is recommended to go for JDK/JRE 1.8+ due to security flaws in 7-

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Nginx as the reverse proxy for Tomcat 7 in Ubuntu 16.04. But of course, Grails 3 using Java 8, that you should install before install Tomcat 7.

You can find [this short article](https://www.djamware.com/post/588df76680aca722878a364a/install-nginx-tomcat-7-and-java-8-on-ubuntu-1604) for production deployment server.